# How can I search for my list of Twitter mutes?

Tags: twitter, mute

Muting people is sometimes useful to avoid the flood of tweets / mentions in a discussion you're no longer interested in. Sometimes it's only temporary, so...

How can I view a list of all the people I've muted so I can unmute some of them back into my timeline?

Will all older tweets mentioning your Twitter handle resurface right back to the '*Notifications*' tab after you unmute them?

Answer (score 3):

After rewording a few times in Google, finally found it with: *"manage twitter mutes"*

Just visit this settings page dedicated to managing your muted members:
https://twitter.com/settings/muted

And you will be presented with something like this:

[image: no description]
***Image courtesy of Martin Brinkmann at www.ghacks.net***

Original link: 
http://www.ghacks.net/2014/09/04/how-to-manage-muted-accounts-on-twitter/